# Modeling end-blown flute instrument using adaptive filter

Tags: acoustics, flute, frequency

I want to find the resonant frequency of specific [end-blown flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-blown_flute) called [Persian ney](http://persianney.com/technique.html), Using LMS in arrangement of system identification. Two signal is needed for algorithm:

1. system excitation (`x`)
2. desired signal (`d`).

[image: General adaptive system identifier]

The plant here is flute. The adaptive is coefficients describing flute behavior in time and frequency. Almost mostly `x` is white noise. The microphone outside the flute will capture the sound as `d`. All done.
But mechanical-acoustic arrangement is like:

```
 -----------  Tubes, conducting acoustic: 
|           | Including big tube, tube reducer and small tube (flute size)
|Noise(x)  / --------------\
|generator| |               -----*-------------- - - ----- --- --- 
|speaker  | |               -----*------ -------------------------
|box       \ --------------/ Flute entrance
|           |                                   O
 -----------                                    | Microphone(d)

* Marks flute entrance
```

Exciting approach seems to be wrong since to make flute work in playing time, we enclose all over flute entrance with lips, only small piece of it's circle remains open to let air move out and make friction with flute edge. If do not enclose, the instrument will not sound!

Small area marked with red is an open area(between teeth and tongue):
[image: Flute excitation small exhaust gap]

The question is how to model this type of flute excitation correctly? Since the white noise must enter the flute, but also it's entrance must be closed.

I'm not sure if maybe human lung also contribute to it's resonance.

Comment: There are easier ways to find the resonant frequency. Try starting here:  https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/fluteacoustics.html. Most of that link is about traverse-blown flutes, but the same principles apply for neys. You are going to need to experimentally measure the end correction due to the embouchure (it's going to vary depending on exactly how much the embouchure hole is covered).

Comment: Also relevant https://www.chrysalis-foundation.org/musical-mathematics-pages/flute-tone-holes/

Comment: @PiedPiper Maybe the flute has made traverse-blown to help tuning and increasing it's frequency response accuracy. Thanks.